# Repeat CXF request in case of error

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I have an OSGi service which I have exposed with CXF as a simple web service and for which I have created a client which invokes its methods. The methods of this service accept as one of their arguments a signed ticket which identifies the client performing the request. In order to inject this ticket to all requests coming from my client I have created a CXF out interceptor, which I have bound to the SETUP phase, and which is responsible for the injection of the ticket in the outgoing message.

In case the ticket injected by my interceptor has expired, the service will throw an exception which I would like to be able to catch, get a fresh ticket and repeat the request with this fresh ticket in order to completely abstract the ticket-management functionality from the rest of my code. I have therefore created an in fault interceptor, which I have bound to the PRE_LOGICAL phase and in which I am able to identify whether the specific exception type I am interested in has been thrown. I am however unsure as to how I can repeat the request and return the result of the second request instead of the first one. Does CXF offer a way for me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I wasn't able to find a way to repeat the request through a fault interceptor I ended up using an InvocationHandler to allow me to control the request (effectively wrapping the proxy I get from CXF in another proxy). What I ended up with is something like the following:

```
ClientProxyFactoryBean factory = new ClientProxyFactoryBean();
// Configure factory
MyService serviceClient = (MyService) factory.create(MyService.class);
MyService  proxy = (MyService) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
        ServiceInvocationHandler.class.getClassLoader(), 
        new Class[] { MyService.class },
        new ServiceInvocationHandler(serviceClient));
```

Where the ServiceInvocationHandler is:

```
public class ServiceInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private final Object proxied;
    private SignedTicket ticket;

    public ServiceInvocationHandler(Object proxied) {
        this.proxied = proxied;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
            throws Throwable {
        Object retVal = null;
        try {
            // Generate a ticket if the one held locally by this class is null
            // and inject it in the method arguments
            retVal = method.invoke(proxied, args);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            if (t.getCause() instanceof InvalidTicketException) {
                // Get a fresh ticket and inject it in the method arguments
                retVal = method.invoke(proxied, args);
            }
        }    
        return retVal;
    }
}
```